# Am I using Powershell's TrimEnd correcty?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to take some raw data at the moment with Powershell and massage it into SQL Insert Statements.  The first order of business is to remove two commas at the end of each of the lines of raw data (before slapping the SQL code before and after the data).  I've been playing around with the Powershell 'TrimEnd' to try to get this done but the following iterations just don't seem to be removing even the first comma from the end of the lines:

```
Sample 1 - (get-content -ErrorAction "Stop" source-file.txt) | Foreach-Object -ErrorAction "Stop" {$_.TrimEnd()} | out-file destination-file.sql

Sample 2 - (get-content -ErrorAction "Stop" source-file.txt) | Foreach-Object -ErrorAction "Stop" {$_.TrimEnd(',')} | out-file destination-file.sql

Sample 3 - (get-content -ErrorAction "Stop" source-file.txt) | Foreach-Object -ErrorAction "Stop" {$_.TrimEnd(",")} | out-file destination-file.sql

Sample 4 - (get-content -ErrorAction "Stop" source-file.txt) | Foreach -ErrorAction "Stop" {$_.TrimEnd()} | out-file destination-file.sql
```

The source-file.txt look something like this:

foo, foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, ,

What I'm hoping to end up with is:

foo, foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5,

Times 200K

Is the problem that I'm not escaping the character or is the 'Foreach/Foreach-Object' not the way to go here?  I'd like to make sure I'm going down the right path before I remove both commas at the end of the source-file.txt file.

Comment: What version of powershell are you using? Sample 2 and 3 should do the job

Comment: Powershell Version 3.0

Comment: I've just tried it on Powershell 3.0 and that also works as expected. Again, it's example 2 and 3 that produce the required. I can send you a screenshot if you want

Comment: See my answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have fatfingered something or have been staring at the screen too long but I leveraged #2 from the suggestion from @Musaab-Al-Okaidi.  I leveraged `{$_.TrimEnd(', ,')}` to get what I needed for what I'm doing.  Cheers!

Comment: No worries. But wouldn't {$_.TrimEnd(', ,')} remove both commas at the end? I thought you wanted to leave one of them.

Comment: Because of the challenges I was facing with trying to get TrimEnd to work I wanted to start with the simple task and get that working before adding complexity to it.